# Question about ESD wristband and lightning

Tags: esd, electrical, grounding, lightning

as far as I know all ESD wristband's ground connection has an 1M ohm resistor built in for safety. So what would happen if I am working on lab wearing ESD wristband which is connected to the home electrical earth and at that moment lightning strikes nearby or on electrical earth line? Will I get hurt? Or will it be safe because of that 1M Resistor?
Thanks.

Comment: Then you'll see a flash followed by a loud bang.

Comment: What about me? :P

Comment: As I said, you'll do the seeing and hearing.

Comment: So I will be safe right? For that 1M resistor?

Comment: that 1M isn't there for your safety... it is their to discharge the static you have accumulated at a safe rate for the ELECTRONICS

Comment: Lets say you are strapped and you pick up some electronics that has been sat on a non-dissipative bench (and thus is charged w.r.t. you). The rate that the electronics dissipates its accumulated charged is related to the discharge resistor: 1M = low current bleed 0R = high current bleed.

Comment: As to the question... Depends... what are you touching at the time. If you are touching a FIRMER earth then the earth point your strap is connected to (ie think cable impedance), there could be a voltage difference produced between your strap bonding point and hte point you are touching. Those 1M are probably only good for 100V (small leaded resistors)

Comment: Simply put you are probably going to be fine but I doubt anyone here would go on the record to state you will be safe without knowing specifics and equally bounding the conditions where you would be safe ESPECIALLY considering the abysmal wiring around the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1M resistor will probably do little for your safety in the event of a direct lightning strike, it would flash over in a moment.

Being indoors, the general Faraday cage effect of the building would mean you are orders of magnitude safer there than outside, whether ESD-strapped or not.

If you were holding an antenna cable that went to the roof without being grounded, then that would pretty much negate all the safety of being indoors, and likely make the ESD strap more hazardous than not. But if you are in an environment where you should be wearing a strap, everything else should be grounded anyway, so that's not likely to happen.